# Does a dotted font exist?

Tags: fonts, logo, font-recommendation

Trying to do some new logos using a dotted font liek the image below.

Does anyone know of any dotted fonts that exist in Google, Adobe or other?

[image]

http://postimg.org/image/ebk1nqi7l/

Comment: Hello user62043, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. I do not want to be rude, but have you tried googling your question first? As @Marcin says, [a quick Google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=dotted+fonts&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=rHzdVsW5O6mr6ASasa8Q) gives some 800.000 results. Please have a look at the [help] to know what this site is about. Keep contributing and enjoy your time here!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, dotted fonts are everywhere. Example: http://www.dafont.com/search.php?q=dotted

Comment: When recommending a font please include the screenshot of the font.

Comment: @Darth_Vader he's linking to a font search, so this doesn't really apply :)

Comment: User still could take a couple of the returned query and link to some of the screenshots and fonts.  Would end up a better answer then a link only answer.

Comment: Instead of next time why not make an [edit] now?  You may likely receive more rep by doing so..

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of dotted fonts. 
Try to [google](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dotted%20font) for dotted fonts, and you get "few" answers.